# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'call' [Решено]

Tags: javascript

Консоль в гуглХроме ругается на след код:

```
function isBd(user) {
    $.get('/index/8-0-' + user, function (data) {
        var bDate = new Date(Number($("#ubd", data).text()) * 1000);
        var date = new Date();
        if ((bDate.getMonth() == date.getMonth()) && (bDate.getDate() == date.getDate())) {
            $('.bd' + user).html('<img src="h/sml/okore.gif" style="margin: 75px 80px 0px 100px; position: absolute;" alt="" width="64pxpxpx" height="64pxpxpx">');
        }
    })
}
```

В чем проблема?

Comment: Почему вы решили, что именно на этот код? Показать страницу можете?

Comment: А на какую строчку именно? Вы привели слишком много кода.

Comment: @Zhukov Roman: может, там доисторическая версия jQuery?

Comment: @VladD: очень много неизвестных. Вообще я бы сначала посмотрел весь callstack.

Comment: без этого кода ошибка не вылетает.
версия jQuery  1.3.2

Comment: Попробуйте использовать jQuery 1.0, возможно это решит проблему.

Comment: @Zhukov Roman Спасибо за совет. поменял на 1.7.2. Все ок))))

Comment: Написал это ответом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery 1.3 выпустили в начале 2009 г., а сейчас уже 2013. Советую использовать последнюю стабильную версию библиотеки.

Answer (score 0):

Сдаётся мне собака вот тут порылась:

```
$("#ubd", data).text()
```

PS. А вот это что за поток сознания? ...width="64pxpxpx" height="64pxpxpx"... ?

Comment: опечатка))
Не подскажете как отрыть эту собаку? а то я в этом деле новичок))

Comment: Ошибка в консоли хрома обычно указывает на определенный файл и определенную строку в этом файле. Вышеприведенный код не содержит метода call, а в ошибке упоминается именно он. Сделайте скриншот консоли с ошибкой.

Comment: У меня нет под рукой гадальных карт . Без полного листинга не получится.

Comment: @istem, а что тут, собственно, не так?

     $("#ubd", data).text()